# php jquery include not working very well

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am stacked at one issue that drives me crazy. I made a left floating file tree view and I include my website. But When I include my web site my file treeview, My treeview does not be clickable[at chrome] also, int IE 9 my thumbnail part for viewing pdf document doesn not opened. Chrome is most important than my other my troubles.

Let me give me codes
 item id is my left menu.

```
<div id="item" style="float:left">
<?php include("leftmenu.php"); ?>
</div>
```

sample include method.

also sidebarOpenfile is file treeview show button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sidebarOpenfile').click(function()  
{

if ($('#item').css("height")=='0px')
{

    $('#item').animate({height:"700px"});
} 
else 
{

    $('#item').animate({height:"0px"});
}
 }); 
 });
```

Above 2 codes is in my main page (.php file).

Also my main page php file's css (#item part):

```
#item {
position:relative;
margin-left:0px;
float:left;
 top: 10px;
width: 200px;
height:0px;
bottom: 0px;
  background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
  overflow:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Finally my leftmenu.php files codes

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#leftmenu').fileTree({ root: '../', script:    'fileview/connectors/jqueryFileTree.php', folderEvent: 'click', expandSpeed: 750, collapseSpeed: 750, multiFolder: false }, function(file) { 
                alert(file);
            });
});
```

Thats all. And All file that is includes is valid and its working.  My problem is

[image: my problem]

Thanks for helping..

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `z-index`. Have a look. Otherwise provide some more info, like the HTML / CSS where your `#item` is in.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible Mistake :)

I cant believe how I can miss.

You're right putvande.

All I need only changing z-index property.

If anyone who have similar problem, they can solving with adding z-index property to their css file.